# SPI0 CE_0 dosn't works

Tags: gpio, spi

I use custom board with raspberry pi
on SPI0 CE0 I have connected SC16IS752 (spi-uart IC)
on SPI0 CE1 MCP2515 (can IC)

I have problem with init this first device

```
GPIO 7: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_CE1_N
GPIO 8: level=1 fsel=1 func=OUTPUT
GPIO 9: level=1 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_MISO
GPIO 10: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_MOSI
GPIO 11: level=0 fsel=4 alt=0 func=SPI0_SCLK
```

GPIO8 don't use func=SPI0_CE0_N, I init SPI0 in /boot/config.txt

```
dtparam=spi=on
```

What I should change?

Comment: What is actually your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing.

The Linux SPI driver does not put the slave select GPIO into SPI mode, it leaves them in OUTPUT mode and drives them directly.